# Subtracting time from a date in Excel

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a cell in column 3 that contains a datetime: `5/12/2011 8:13AM`. I'm looking to subtract x hours from this time.

So far, I have this:

```
=A3-TIME(8,0,0)
```

It's not working. How should the formula be written?

Comment: It *is* working. What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: I confirm that it is working.

Comment: ok, it is working; I was getting a #NAME error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [DateAdd](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080557155.aspx) instead of voodoo/rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the space between 13 and AM.